# Passing request context implicitly in an actor system

Tags: scala, akka, actor, implicit-conversion, implicit

I would like to propagate a request context implicitly in a system of collaborating actors.

To simplify and present the situation, my system has multiple actors and the messages passed to these actors need to include this RequestContext object.

ActorA receives messages of type MessageA
ActorB receives messages of type MessageB

when ActorA needs to send a message to ActorB, as part of the handling of MessageA, it performs business logic, and then constructs a MessageB from results of the logic as well as the RequestContext available in MessageA and then sends it to ActorB

```
def handle(ma:MessageA) {
 val intermediateResult = businessLogic(ma)
 actorB ! MessageB(intermediateResult, ma.requestContext)
}
```

We have a slew of messages to be handled, and explicitly passing around the requestContext is cumbersome.

I am trying of creative ways to use Scala's implicits feature to avoid explicitly injecting the RequestContext embedded within incoming message into the outgoing message.

The messages are case classes (and they need to be). I have read about implicits rules but bringing an attribute of an object into current implicit scope appears far-fetched.

This, I am sure should be a common requirement. 
Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way is to make your val implicit in the case class.

```
case class MessageA(req: RequestA)(implicit val ctx: RequestContext)

case class MessageB(req: RequestB)(implicit val ctx: RequestContext)

def businessLogic(req:RequestA):RequestB


def handle(ma: MessageA): Unit = {
  // import all the members of ma so that there is a legal implicit RequestContext in scope
  import ma._
  val intermediateResult = businessLogic(req)
  actorB ! MessageB(intermediateResult)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I seriously considered this approach, but I gave up thinking that passing the parameter explicitly is far more readable and less verbose than adding all the imports and implicits in order to use the feature - don't you think?

Comment: If that is a problem, I would factor out a message processor, which is a MessageA => MessageB and just call it in the body of the actor. This would also enhance testability

Answer (score 6):

In your example your handling of the message in question is factored out into a method already, which makes this straight-forward:

```scala
trait RequestContext

case class MessageA(req: RequestA, ctx: RequestContext)
object MessageA {
  def apply(req: RequestA)(implicit ctx: RequestContext) = MessageA(req, ctx)
}

case class MessageB(req: RequestB, ctx: RequestContext)
object MessageB {
  def apply(req: RequestB)(implicit ctx: RequestContext) = MessageB(req, ctx)
}

class Example extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case MessageA(req, ctx) => handle(req)(ctx)
  }

  def handle(req: RequestA)(implicit ctx: RequestContext): Unit = {
    val intermediateResult = businessLogic(req) // could take implicit ctx as well
    actorB ! MessageB(intermediateResult)
  }
}
```

But as you can see there is still some overhead when declaring the message types, and the `handle` method’s signature also needs to be altered. Whether this scheme is worth it depends on the ratio between consumers and producers of these implicit values (i.e. if more than one thing in `handle` uses the context it makes more sense).

A variation of the above could be:

```scala
case class MessageA(req: RequestA, ctx: RequestContext)
object MessageA {
  def apply(req: RequestA)(implicit ctx: RequestContext) = MessageA(req, ctx)
  implicit def toContext(implicit msg: MessageA) = msg.ctx
}

case class MessageB(req: RequestB, ctx: RequestContext)
object MessageB {
  def apply(req: RequestB)(implicit ctx: RequestContext) = MessageB(req, ctx)
  implicit def toContext(implicit msg: MessageB) = msg.ctx
}

...
def handle(implicit ma: MessageA): Unit = {
  val intermediateResult = businessLogic(req)
  actorB ! MessageB(intermediateResult)
}
```

Comment: why an implicit message? isn't the request which should be implicit? see my answer

Comment: @Roland, your idea inspired a neater approach. If MessageA and MessageB inherit from AbstractMessage, and we provide an implicit conversion from AbstractMessage to a RequestContext within AbstractMessage's companion object, then the problem is solved! All that each message needs to do is declare an implicit request context param, and as along as one is available, it will be passed along!

Comment: Well... I got over excited... it turns out that marking every handle method with implicit MessageA parameter is necessary for this to work, but does not make it readable. The implicit declarations propagate too much over business logic code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic envelope class holding both original message and context. Create a trait extending `Actor` (you have to place it in `akka._` package). Override method `aroundReceive()` that unpacks your envelope, initializes an actor's protected variable for storing the current context, calls the original receive method with the unpacked message, uninitializes the context variable. Rather a dubious approach, but this is exactly how `Actor.sender()` behaves.

To send a message to such a context-bound actor, you have to wrap your message into the envelope mentioned above manually, or you can automate this task as well by introducing an extension over `ActorRef` that implements tell/ask operations by lifting the message to context-bound.

This is not just a concept but a brief summary of the approach I recently tried with success. Moreover, I generalized it some more by introducing another abstract concept — implicit context environments like actor-based, ThreadLocal-based, Future-based, etc what enabled me to easily pass context data throughout all sync/async chain of operations implicitly.